# Como hacer para insertar datos a tablas relacionadas con primary key autoincremental?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

bueno me surgio un problemita pasa que tengo mi diagrama de clases y quiero insertar datos a 5 tablas que estan relacionadas entre si
aqui les muestro mis tablas que tengo y tambien les pondre una imagen de todo mi diagrama que hecho de este pequeñito sistema q estoy haciendo pero aqui va mi problema , q pasa si yo quiero insertar datos en esas 5 tablas que les menciono empezando por la primera que es ubicacion hasta terminar con anuncio para no tener problema con llave foraneas etc , si lo inserto asi tabla por tabla en ese orden que les digo todo bien , pero claro yo no inserto los IDs de cada tabla porque son autoincrementales pero como recojo ese id para poder insertar en la otra tabla siguiente como foranea? para esto me surgio la idea de hacer una consulta a la tabla que se inserto y recojer su id (recojiendo su ultima fila insertada de la tabla obviamente) para obtenerla y ponerla cono clave foranea de la siguiente tabla que voy a insertar que la requiere y asi sucesivamente hasta insertar todas las tablas verdad. ahora me surgieron otras inquietudes aparte imaginemosno que a esta base de datos van a insertar muchas personas datos a esas 5 tablas tambien al mismo tiempo entonces la idea que le dije anteriormente no funcionaria cierto? porque puede llegar a darse el caso que la inserccion de una tal persona se mezcle con la inserccion de otra persona verdad? o no puede llegar ese caso? yo creo que si verdad?  pues segun yo q tal si al recoger el id de una tabla (ultima fila) pero no era esa ultima fila si no la penultima fila (pasa esto porque muchos insertan a la misma vez) y entonces al insertar a la otra tabla como foranea el id recojido va insertar otro id que no debia y asi todo una mezcla infinita. como se resolveria este problema? hay alguna manera de insertar en esas 5 tablas pero que no afecte a otras insercciones? osea que yo al insertar esas 5 tablas obviamente en el orden q le dejo abajo se inserten como un solo conjunto para que no afecte a otras insercciones? y como se haria para evitar esas consultas de obtener el ultimo id insertado , etc etc? bueno amigos solo espero que me ayuden ya q no tengo ni idea como se haria aqui en ese caso muchas gracias. lo estoy haciendo en php y phpmyadmin :).

tabla ubicacion:

```
 id (es primary key autoincremental (entero))
 direccion (varchar)
 zona (varchar)
 dpto (varchar)
  latitud (double)
 longitud (double)
```

tabla producto_inmueble:

```
 id(primary key es autoincrementable)
 precio (int)
 estado (varchar)
 id_ubicacion (clave foranea que se relaciona con la tabla ubicacion (id))
```

tabla galeria:

```
  id (primary key es autoincrementable)
  url(text)
  id_prod_inmueble(clave foranea que se relaciona con la tabla 
   producto_inmueble(id))
    imagen(longblob)
    ruta (varchar)
```

tabla detalle_inmueble

```
   id(primary key es autoincrementable)
    ..... mas atributos
    id_prod_inmu(clave foranea que se relaciona con la tabla 
    producto_inmueble)
```

tabla anuncio:

```
  id ((entero)es primary key autoimcremental)
  estado (varchar)
  fecha_ini (date)
  titulo (text)
   descripcion (text)
   id_prod_inmu (esta es foranea que se relaciona con tabla 
   producto_inmueble(id))
    ci_cliente (es foranea se relaciona con cliente(ci))
   id_deta_auncio (esta relacionado osea es foranea con la tabla 
   Detalle_anuncio (esta tabla es estatica)) aqui no hay problema
   id_categoria ( es foranea con id de la tabla categoria que tambien es 
   tabla estatica)
```

[image: lo que esta dentro de lo marcado con rojo son las tablas que les digo]

Comment: No es necesario que estas haciendo una consulta nuevamente. Debes usar [LAST_INSERT_ID()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) con eso se solucionaría tu problema. Lo que debes hacer es crearte un procedimiento almacenado. Realizas un insert y a continuación agarras el ultimo id con esa función y sigues haciendo el resto de ese modo.

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS AMIGO, ME SALVASTE CON ESA FUNCION :) JEJE.

Comment: amigo una pregunta disculpa que te moleste nuevamente, tambien funcionaria si no lo hago por procedimiento almacenado? no habria problema o si o si hay que hacer con PA?

Comment: No molestas. Si, se puede. En realidad seria lo correcto hacerlo por procedimiento(desde mi punto de vista y experiencia). Saludos!

Comment: ahh listo muchas gracias por tu tiempo :).